# No me agrega la fila en la tabla mediante Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Debo de agregar filas a una tabla mediante Jquery, no he podido ver el error en la consola, en la magen se aprecia lo que debo de hacer después de darle clic al botón agregar invitado del formulario modal:
[image: tabla html cuyas filas se deben insertar con jquery]
[image: Formulario modal]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){
        addRow();
    });
});

//Adiciona una fila con los datos a la tabla
function addRow() { 
    const row = createRow({    
          firstName: $('first-name').val(),
          lastName:  $('last-name').val(),  
          celPhone:  $('mobile-number').val(),
          confirmed: $('confirmed').val()});   
    $('tbody').prepend(row);  
    clean(); 
  } 

//Crea los datos de la fila de la tabla
function createRow(data) {  return (    
       `<tr>` +     
         `<td>${data.firstName}</td>` +    
         `<td>${data.lastName}</td>` +   
         `<td>${data.celphone}</td>` +    
         `<td>${data.confirmed}</td>` +  
       `</tr>`  
      ); 
}

//Limpia los dato que ingresa el usuario
function clean() {
  $('#firstName').val('');
  $('#lasttName').val('');
  $('#celPhone').val('');
  $('#confirmed').val('');
  $('#firstName').focus();
}
```

```css
action {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lista de Invitados</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <h1>Lista de Invitados</h1>

        <div class="action text-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-guest">Nuevo Invitado</button>
        </div>

        <table class="table bordered-table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Apellido</th>
              <th class="text-center">Celular</th>
              <th class="text-center">Confirmado</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
               
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="new-guest" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="new-guest">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Invitado</h4>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="first-name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombre:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name" autofocus>  
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="last-name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Apellido:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="mobile-number" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Celular:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile-number">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="confirmed"> Confirmado
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="submit" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar Invitado</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está básicamente en que al momento de agregar la fila , se envía el formulario que tiene dentro de la modal . para lo cuál la solución más próxima es eliminar esta etiqueta , ya que no es necesario para este proceso en particular.

Luego tiene otro error en la función `addRow()` asumo que intenta obtener los valores de los `input` , para esto debe hacer referencia a su id por lo cuál hace falta el `#`.

En la función `createRow()` cuando intenta acceder al valor del teléfono, la letra **p** es mayúscula `celPhone`. En la función `clean()` también tiene errores al seleccionar los elementos y limpiar su contenido. Para el checkbox debería usar `.prop('checked', false);` para "deschecked".

Para la opción del `check` en la tabla puede utilizar un operador ternario para saber si se selecciono el `checkbox` `.is(':checked')` si es así , agregar un `span` con la clase `fa fa-check` caso contrario no mostrar nada *(puede mostrar un span con otra clase también)*

```
($('#confirmed').val())?'<span class="fa fa-check"></span>':''
```

**Ejm Completo**

```js
$(function() {
   $("#add").click(function(){
      addRow();
  });
});

//Adiciona una fila con los datos a la tabla
function addRow() { 
    const row = createRow({    
          firstName: $('#first-name').val(),
          lastName:  $('#last-name').val(),  
          celPhone:  $('#mobile-number').val(),
          confirmed: ($('#confirmed').is(':checked'))?'<span class="fa fa-check"></span>':''
        });   
    $('tbody').prepend(row);  
    clean(); 
  } 

//Crea los datos de la fila de la tabla
function createRow(data) {  return (    
       `<tr>` +     
         `<td>${data.firstName}</td>` +    
         `<td>${data.lastName}</td>` +   
         `<td>${data.celPhone}</td>` +    
         `<td>${ data.confirmed}</td>` +  
       `</tr>`  
      ); 
}

//Limpia los dato que ingresa el usuario
function clean() {
  $('#first-name').val('');
  $('#last-name').val('');
  $('#mobile-number').val('');
  $('#confirmed').prop('checked', false);
  $('#first-name').focus();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <h1>Lista de Invitados</h1>

        <div class="action text-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-guest">Nuevo Invitado</button>
        </div>

        <table class="table bordered-table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Apellido</th>
              <th class="text-center">Celular</th>
              <th class="text-center">Confirmado</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
               
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="new-guest" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="new-guest">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Invitado</h4>
        </div>
   
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="first-name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombre:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name" autofocus>  
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="last-name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Apellido:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="mobile-number" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Celular:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile-number">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="confirmed"> Confirmado
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="submit" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar Invitado</button>
          </div>
 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Si no puede modificar el código `HTML` por diversos motivos , simplemente a la implementación anterior debe evitar el comportamiento del `submit` con el típico `e.preventDefault()`

```
$(function() {
   $("#add").click(function(e){
      addRow();
      //Linea adicional con la etiqueta Form
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Dev. Joel, no puedo modificar el html, debo trabajar solo con la implementación del Jquery. Modificó algo del codigo html?

Comment: @GarcíaHenry añadí una pequeña actualización para la  cuando  no pueda modificar el HTML.

Comment: ya me agrega la fila pero la colunma del checkbox no me crea el signo de chequeo.

Comment: No debe olvidar añadir la librería de font-awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Con la clase que viene en Bootstrap se puede agregar símbolo de chequeo

```
($('#confirmed').is(':checked'))?'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>':''
```